# Huge Difference On Connecting to Local and Remote MySQL DB in Same Machine

Tags: mysql, php, vmware-esxi, database, mariadb

I have a **rest-full** php 7 web service app in a **centos 7** vm and **mariadb 10.4** as database.
I **have to** seperate database to another vm beside main vm on same machine,
my question is why diffrence of request per second (RPS) between is **huge**
in local db I have 2500 rps avg, but on remote db with vmxnet3 adaptor (esxi) I have about 1100
I tested already skip-name-resolve in my.cnf
how can I fix ?
Is there any part that I missed?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES` on each, then see what items are different.  A few starting with `innodb` could cause that much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you performance reduces from 2500 qps to 1100 qps when you put your database on a separate VM? If so, additional latency would be my first guess. Especially since you are going between two virtual machines. Not only will that double the amount of context switching required, but context switching can be orders of magnitude more expensive with virtual machines. This can be even worse if you are overbooking the CPU.